# How to use sendtextmessageasync method?

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to use `sendtextmessageasync` method but I cannot fill first and last overload with appropriate value.

```
private static void Bot_OnMessage(object sender, Telegram.Bot.Args.MessageEventArgs e)
   {
        Telegram.Bot.Types.KeyboardButton button1 = new Telegram.Bot.Types.KeyboardButton("a");
        Telegram.Bot.Types.KeyboardButton button2 = new Telegram.Bot.Types.KeyboardButton("b");
        Telegram.Bot.Types.KeyboardButton button3 = new Telegram.Bot.Types.KeyboardButton("c");
        Telegram.Bot.Types.KeyboardButton button4 = new Telegram.Bot.Types.KeyboardButton("d");

        Telegram.Bot.Types.KeyboardButton[] row1 = { button1, button2 };
        Telegram.Bot.Types.KeyboardButton[] row2 = { button3, button4 };

        Telegram.Bot.Types.KeyboardButton[][] keyboard = { row1, row2 };

        Telegram.Bot.Types.ReplyMarkups.ReplyKeyboardMarkup markup = new Telegram.Bot.Types.ReplyMarkups.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard);

        bot.SendTextMessageAsync(e.Message.Chat.Id, "Hi", , false, false, 0, markup, );

        Console.WriteLine("A new message has been recieved");
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this [github issue](https://github.com/TelegramBots/telegram.bot.examples/issues/5) should give you the right start.

```
var reply = "<b>Hello</b>\n"
            + "<a href=\"https://www.google.de\">This is a link</a>\n"
            + "<code>and a little bit code</code>";

await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, reply, parseMode: ParseMode.Html);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use await command to await the result if the current method and all calling methods have the async keyword, and return either a `Task` or `Task<T>` where T is the type being returned. `var result = await SendTextMessageAsync()`

Otherwise, you can use `SendTextMessageAsync.ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, but this is not ideal as it could result in a deadlock unless all calls in the call path are using `ConfigureAwait(false)`. This command indicates that the result can come back on any thread.

More info can be found here: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html